# Why my tokensMatch() method is not working on Laravel?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, fetch-api, sanctum

Inside VerifyCsrfToken.php in `tokenMatch()` method the  `hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);` method is having some error 419. I am building a SPA with React and a Laravel API Sanctum, making a manual request with fetch get request retrieving the csrf token from the built-in endpoint and sending it with a fetch post to for build a page to register and login automatically.
The thing is that the `$request->session()->token()` is always changing on each request but the $token is not.
`$request->session()->token()` is generated by framework (I guess) and `$token` is a decrypted `XCRF-TOKEN`. I sent to this API on POST request. So the `hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);` is always mismatching because I have a fixed token and a variable one. I am new with Laravel so I was just disarming the code in pieces until reach this and got stuck.

It is like the fetch get request to 'http://localhost:8000/sanctum/csrf-cookie' is always sending me the same csrf token. is that how it suppose to work?

```
protected function tokensMatch($request)
    {
        $token = $this->getTokenFromRequest($request);

        return is_string($request->session()->token()) &&
               is_string($token) &&
               hash_equals($request->session()->token(), $token);
    }
```

by the way this is the fetch post request of React:

```
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'post',
        body: formData,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-XSRF-TOKEN': decodeURIComponent(tokenCookie['XSRF-TOKEN']),
        },
    });
```

If you are wondering what is that `decodeURIComponent(tokenCookie['XSRF-TOKEN'])`, well it is because Chrome add some characters the incoming csrf token from get request at the end of string (%3D); I don't know why.

I just want to fix that `hash_equal()` problem.